# how to pass parameter to function and change the route

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.6

1- it is possible to use redirectToRoute() for passing an object ?

```
$ccp = new Ccp();
return ($this->redirectToRoute("_indexAccountCcpClient",array('ccp'=>$ccp)));
```

this is my yml routing :

```
_indexCcpClient:
    path:     /index
    defaults: { _controller: EgovPosteBundle:Ccp:indexCcp }

_indexAccountCcpClient:
    path:     /account/index
    defaults: { _controller: EgovPosteBundle:Ccp:indexAccountCcp }
```

my controller

```
public function indexCcpAction()
    {
        $demanceCCP = new DemandeCCP();
        $ccp = new Ccp();
        $formDemanceCCP = $this->createForm(new DemandeCcpType(), $demanceCCP);
        $formCcp = $this->createForm(new LoginCcpType(), $ccp);
        $formCcp->handleRequest($this->get('request'));
        $formDemanceCCP->handleRequest($this->get('request'));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if ($this->get("request")->getMethod() == "POST") {
            if ($this->get("request")->request->has("DemandeCcpType")) {
                $demanceCCP = $formDemanceCCP->getData();
                $em->persist($demanceCCP);
                $em->flush();
            }
            if ($this->get("request")->request->has("LoginCcpType")) {
                $ccp = $formCcp->getData();
                $dbCcp = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EgovCoreBundle:Ccp')
                    ->findOneBy(array('numCompte' => $ccp->getNumCompte(), 'mdp' => $ccp->getMdp()));
                if (!$dbCcp) {
                    throw $this->createNotFoundException('No Data found for id ');
                } else {
                    self::indexAccountCcpAction($ccp);
                    //return ($this->redirectToRoute("_indexAccountCcpClient",array('ccp'=>$ccp)));
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->render('@EgovPoste/Ccp/indexCcp.html.twig',
            array('formDemandeCcp' => $formDemanceCCP->createView(),
                  'formLogin' => $formCcp->createView())
        );
    }
public function indexAccountCcpAction(Ccp $ccp)
    {
        //echo ($ccp->getNumCompte());

        return $this->render('EgovPosteBundle:Ccp:indexAccountCcp.html.twig', array('ccp' => $ccp));
    }
```

So my probleme is how can i call indexAccountCcpAction(Ccp $ccp) function and change the route path to /account/index

in my code it work fine but with the same path : /index

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass an object to a controller, you can only pass a string value when you redirect, like in any URL.

So pass the id from $dpCcp to the controller when you redirect, then in indexAccountCcpAction load the object from the database with a repository method.